# Data edit on TinyMce in php

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

I fetch data from database and want to edit that data and display on tinymce editor but data not display on editor. When i remove TinyMce Pulgin then data display on text area.

```
function edit(id, conte) {
    d = document.FormName;
    d.lid.value = lid;
    $(function () {
        $("#lang").change(function () {
            var s = $(this).val(conte); //conte is hidden
            var name alert(s);
            tinyMCE.get('conte').setContent(content); // content is textarea name and id
            alert(conte);
        });
    });
    d.content.value = conte;
    document.getElementById("form-tab").innerHTML = "Edit Category";
    d.submitButton.value = "Add Content";
    d.action.value = "edit";
    $("#formHide").show("slow");
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Actually tinymce editor giving you complete documentation about how to use editor.

When you call tinymce editor js file in your header like that

```
<script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Now you just write in your header.

```
<script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector:'textarea',
        });
</script>
```

Then it will giving output in your tinymce editor.

Just take a look on home page of tinymce editor website.

http://www.tinymce.com/   Review Quick Install on home page.

Hope It will help you.

Thanks